# pop-window disappeared before filling its fields- selenium

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenide

I need to test login function by having different Juint tests with different username & password values. all tests are located in same Juint. I use the following JAR files:

[image]

or these tests, browser will be only opened for the first test and closed at the last test.

My notes:

1. for chrome browser (v2.9.24) , all tests have successful run.
2. when I used the latest firefox browser(v45.0.1), only first test has a successful run and others are failed.
3. some of them can't catch the pop-window to enter values, and then it will continue for the next test.
4. In some cases, pop-window can't wait, it disappeared quickly and then unit test can't find username and password fields to fill values.

I need to test them on firefox, so how to overcome this problem.

Note:
I tried some of these suggestions but still the previous problem occurred.

```
WebDriverWait waitLog = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver(), 2);             
waitLog.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable($(".modal-dialog")));
```

Or set before test this parameter:

```
Configuration.fastSetValue=true;
```

However, I can't come with a way to solve this problem.

Comment: You'd have a much better chance of getting an answer with a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you try once bit lower version of firefox

Comment: I have to do it for the latest version

Comment: Please see this Q : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647190/different-tests-within-same-juint-firefox-driver-in-selenium